# Nested class property not fill properly from configuration ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I need to fill below info from `appsetting.json` in ASP.NET Core 2.2.

```
"SiteSetting": {
    "JwtSetting": {
      "SecretKey": "LongerThan-16Char-SecretKey",
      "Issuer": "MyWebsite",
      "Audience": "MyWebsite",
      "NotBeforeMinutes": "0",
      "ExpirationMinutes": "60"
    }
}
```

This is my `SiteSetting` class :

```
public class SiteSetting
{
    public JwtSetting JwtSettings { get; set; }
}

public class JwtSetting
{
    public string SecretKey { get; set; }
    public string Issuer { get; set; }
    public string Audience { get; set; }
    public int NotBeforeMinutes { get; set; }
    public int ExpirationMinutes { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm using this code in `Startup.cs` to fill `SiteSetting`:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    private SiteSetting _siteSetting;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _siteSetting = configuration.GetSection(nameof(SiteSetting)).Get<SiteSetting>();
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<SiteSetting>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(SiteSetting)));
    }
```

But when I debug that, the `_siteSetting` is null.

what's the problem? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `AppSettings.json` you defined `JwtSetting` but in `SiteSetting` class, you name that JwtSetting**s**. Class property names and JSON property keys should be exactly the same in order to be parsed automatically.

Change your AppSettings.json like this and that will work properly :

```
"SiteSetting": {
    "JwtSettings": {
      "SecretKey": "LongerThan-16Char-SecretKey",
      "Issuer": "MyWebsite",
      "Audience": "MyWebsite",
      "NotBeforeMinutes": "0",
      "ExpirationMinutes": "60"
    }
}
```

Comment: Where can one learn more about this requirement/limitation?